# Android dynamic number of services

Tags: java, android, process

Is it possible to create a dynamic number of the same process in an Android app?

I've tried using services but it is limited due to problems stated below.

You have to edit the manifest file, to add the service with the class name in the 'android:name' field, thus not being dynamic.

And also it's not possible to start multiple instance of a service.

Edit:
Maybe not exactly dynamic number of the same process, but multiple processes running the same class.

Comment: "Is it possible to create a dynamic number of the same process in an Android app?" -- not that I am aware of. What would this be useful for, particularly in the typical Android environment (battery-, CPU-, and RAM-constrained mobile devices)?

Comment: It probably would not be applicable for almost any Android application. But what I'm doing is creating mobile agents, thus the need for multiple standalone processes to run each agent.

Answer (score 0):

Services are unique instances and they cannot be duplicated.

A good idea might be to create a service that launches and controls different threads that take care of the processes you want your application to perform.